# How to setup and use react router dom for my project

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I am having problem with the react router setup for my project.
This is my code below

Index.js
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnPGU.png)

App.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hnxl.png)

My dependencies
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gDoU.png)

The Error I get
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hyk4B.png)

I tried to install and and use the react router to navigate to different components in my project, but all i get is errors. Someone help me please

Comment: What is unclear about the error you have? React-Router-Dom doesn't export a `BrouserRouter` component. Import and use the `BrowserRouter` component. Voting close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo". Cheers.

Comment: Yes, it was a typo error. I misspelled BrowserRouter for BrouserRouter. Thank you Drew Reese

Answer (score 0):

change your index.js to :

```
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

and no need to root.render(...)

Comment: OP is using React 18. How the root container is rendered changed, so this answer will be incorrect.